# Catching phonegap GapViewClient.onReceivedError in javascript

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

When my phonegap android app is offline, and i try to access a url the app displays an error (GapViewClient.onReceivedError) messagebox and closes. How do I catch the error before it is displayed and closes my app.

Answer (score 0):

Add the below code to your onCreate function and and create a html file with proper message in the asset/www/folder

```
  webViewClient = new WebViewClient() {

        public void onReceivedError( WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl)
        {
            appView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/noConnection.html");
        }
    };
```

For more details visit: http://tech.sarathdr.com/featured/how-to-get-url-not-reached-error-in-anodroid-phonegap