# worklight - App does not connect with server after installation in first attempt

Tags: ios, jquery-mobile, ios7, ibm-mobilefirst

I just updated my App on iOS 7 and when I deployed it on device then it did not connect after the very first installation. I killed the App and re-started it again then it connected.

Same way, on iOS simulator if i first run App then it do not connect but if I re-run it again then it connects. I have tried many times on simulator but same behavior. I even reset the simulator but same behavior.

Is this known issue? Please guide

Comment: What version of Worklight? With latest fixes applied? http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27039574

Comment: could you maybe provide a debug print to see if there is a problem with loading the web resources? maybe it has something to do with the question I already asked once where it did not load the web resources at the first start: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18623390/wl-5-0-6-1-android-updating-app-apk-on-top-of-installed-app-causes-cordova-webv

Comment: I re-generated a fresh code on another Mac machine where only Xcode 5 was installed, and it worked fine. Previously on my Mac machine i had XCode 4.5 & XCode 5 separately, so i assume during generation something could have happened.

Comment: Great news; Abdul, please either delete the question or write the above as an answer and mark it as such. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I re-generated a fresh code on another Mac machine where only Xcode 5 was installed, and it worked fine. Previously on my Mac machine i had XCode 4.5 & XCode 5 separately, so i assume during generation something could have happened.